# .NET library for 3D image transform

Tags: .net, image, transform

Is there a .NET library that allows 3D transform of images?

I want to project a 2D image on different shapes (sphere, Cylindric forms, conic, etc.).
I tried some libraries ([Paint.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paint.NET) script, [AForge.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AForge.NET) with the BackwardQuadrilateralTransformation filter) but no way. I tried to combine different transformation (using AForge.NET) unsuccessfully.

Does a library exist that makes this easy?

Comment: What platform are you developing for (WinForm, ASP, WPF or Silverlight)? For the last two you could look to [Balder](http://balder.codeplex.com/)

Comment: i'm working with asp.net/c#. the client side is svg (Raphael). i should generate preview on the server side (ajax call).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd look at wpf 3d. It's part of .net and you need less boilerplate code to get started as compared to directx. Lastly it will software emulate if there is no GPU.

Answer (score 0):

DirectX might be what you're looking for.